# WHERE clause in nested select

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm having a bit of a problem with a nested select I'm trying to do on a table of data.

I have a number of books across a number of libraries. Each book has an ID and each location a name. Every time a book is taken out or returned, a transaction is recorded on a transaction table.

The table looks a little like this:

```
+---------+--------+----------+------------+
| BOOK_ID | IN_OUT | LOCATION |    DATE    |
+---------+--------+----------+------------+
| B01     | O      | RED      | 2013-10-04 |
| B02     | O      | BLUE     | 2013-10-04 |
| B01     | I      | RED      | 2013-10-19 |
| B01     | O      | RED      | 2013-10-20 |
| B02     | I      | RED      | 2013-10-21 |
| B01     | I      | BLUE     | 2013-10-24 |
+---------+--------+----------+------------+
```

(Thanks, @[Senseful](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/8232)!)

Right now, I can show all transactions and their in_time, out_time displayed in pairs:

```
SELECT i.BOOK_ID
                  ,(SELECT MAX(o.DATE)
                      FROM TRANSACTIONS o
                     WHERE (o.IN_OUT = 'O')
                       AND o.BOOK_ID = i.BOOK_ID
                       AND o.DATE < i.DATE
               ) AS out_time
  , i.DATE AS in_time
  , LOCATION
  FROM TRANSACTIONS i
 WHERE i.IN_OUT = 'I'
 ORDER BY i.DATE
;
```

Now, however, I'm wanting to only display transactions where books are being returned to a different location: so in the example above, I've tried selecting LOCATION as out_location with the intention of adding a WHERE clause to check if it is equal to in_location.

Fair enough:

```
,(SELECT MAX(o.DATE), LOCATION as out_location
                      FROM TRANSACTIONS o
```

No can do. "`ORA-00913: too many values`".

Any ideas on what would be the most sensible way of limiting the output like this?

Comment: You can get results using analyitic functions. Check this question for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824432/oracle-analytic-functions-resetting-a-windowing-clause

Comment: You could add `AND o.location <> i.location` to your inner select, but that doesn't give you the current location of the book.

Comment: @SQB Right, that's looking a bit more promising... evaluates correctly, giving me a `(null)` on the `out_time` as expected. Adding `where ... out_time is not null` on outer select though gives `ORA-00904: "i"."out_time": invalid identifier` - doesn't 'see' that out_time column then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyitic functions are great for this kind of queries. You can use `LEAD` or `LAG` to get the previous or next row in a group.

I created an SQLFiddle example for you: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/725c1/14

The resulting select statement is this:

```
select *
from (
   SELECT i.BOOK_ID
   , i.in_out
   , i.event_date AS in_time
   , LOCATION in_location
   , lag(event_date) over (partition by book_id order by event_date) out_date
   , lag(location) over (partition by book_id order by event_date) out_location
   FROM TRANSACTIONS i
   ORDER BY i.event_date)
where in_out = 'I'
and   in_location != out_location;
```

Comment: Amazing. I now have yet another thing to go read about... analytic functions! Thank you @Alen.

Comment: This is me coming back to thank you again. I've just used it in another context, completely replacing a behemoth of a statement I had. This is beautiful. I feel like a new man. Life is good.

Comment: He he, I'm glad you like it.